# Education factor to immigrate to Germany - Don't have a Degree

Tags: germany, immigration, brazilian-citizens

I don't have a degree. May I apply for a Competency-based Degree in USA, would this be a good degree for immigration to Germany?

This is a Bachelor's, but acquired online.

Please check the program here:

http://flex.wisconsin.edu/blog/category/competency-based-education-2/

Will the program recognize this type of Degree??

Comment: I have my doubts.  Your "degree" will have to be evaluated by a [credential evaluation agency](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/immigrate/skilled/assessment.asp) so you may check with them to see which programs if any will be accepted in this case.  My guess: without completing formal program: **none**

Comment: Which university? Beware of scams in this area.

Comment: @nkjt University of Wisconsin, at least in US this degree qualifies me to any master´s degree.

Comment: University of Wisconsin online?  Or University of Wisconsin in Wisconsin?

Comment: @Karlson This is the University and the program:
http://flex.wisconsin.edu/blog/category/competency-based-education-2/

Just to clarify I meant a master´s in Computer Science

What do you think Guys?

Comment: You should ask them if the Degree they give you is the exact same degree a student on Campus would earn.

Comment: They said. I called some other Universities to see how they validate the credits for Master´s Degree, They said that wouldn't be a problem at all.

Comment: *They said*... what?  The question was whether or not the competency based degree through the Flex program at UW is exactly the same as the on campus one.  Not being a problem is different then equivalence.

Comment: Please don't edit your question like this - you've just made my answer, based on sources about Canada, incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the Flex program is accredited, and from a well-recognised university, it is rather new, and it's hard to say whether it will be accepted as equivalent to a traditional bachelor's degree (including a traditional distance-learning program).

One issue is that if you go through the program quite quickly (which I get the impression is possible under this system) your transcript will show that.

The [ECA results table](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/immigrate/skilled/eca-conversion.asp) suggests that there is a minimum time limit for attendance, as categories include:

- Bachelor's degree or other programs (three or more years) - 21 points for FSW program
- Two year degree, diploma, or certificate - 19 points
- One year degree, diploma, or certificate - 15 points

I don't think there's a simple answer, but you should be aware that there's a very real chance that they consider it "less" than a traditional three/four year program.  On the other hand, they might still consider it equivalent to the one or two year categories, which still gives you a significant number of points, and employers may also look favourably on it.

What you could do is find out who can do an ECA for your job category, and give a them an email asking if they assess distance learning degrees and if there is any official guidance on the matter.